# How to override the style or CSS of an Material UI autocomplete options?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is there a way to change the padding of the options in an Material UI autocomplete Dropdown List?
I would like to remove the padding from all the list items from the dropdown.
[Sample Image of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdCRT.png)

Here is the CodeSandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-paper-in-autocomplete-forked-ntef9?file=/demo.js

Answer (score 1):

You can override `option` css using `makestyles`.

`Autocomplete` component has `classes` [prop](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/#props), using which you can override.

Define style for option

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  option: {
    padding: "0px",
    margin: "1px !important"
  }
});
```

_

```
const classes = useStyles();
```

And then

```
<Autocomplete
  classes={{
    option: classes.option
  }}
  .
  .
  .
/>
```

[Updated Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-paper-in-autocomplete-forked-lmlb1?file=/demo.js)

Ref: https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#overriding-styles-with-classes

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect [image: the sandbox]
and then add the styling in a stylesheet.

Here is the  [edited sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-paper-in-autocomplete-forked-hp71q?file=/demo.css)

Comment: is it possible without the stylesheet i mean, could we use it in the makeStyles within the component?